# An algorithm for a synchronization

Tags: algorithms, synchronization

I want to make a synchronization. What's the algorithm for it in a nutshell?

1) A client reads a local data and sends them to a server **afterwards**. The server compares them with its actual data, decides what are newer and overwrites its data with received data in case received data is newer.

or

2) A client reads data from the server **first**, compares them with its local data and in case data from the server is newer, overrwrites them with the server data.

And does the order matter?

Comment: One good place to start is reading up on how the [MS Synchronization Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/sync/bb821992.aspx) works. It gives you ideas of how you can setup 2 databases for synchronization and what operations are used to do so.  Other tips: use the GUID datatype for your primary keys.

Answer (score 4):

> You should look at how distributed change management works. Look at
>   SVN, CVS and other repositories that manage deltas work.
>
> You have several use cases.
>
> 1. **Synchronize changes**. Clients send their deltas to the server; server consolidates and distributes the deltas to the clients. This is
>      the typical case. Databases call this "transaction replication".
> 2. **Client has lost synchronization**. In this case, the client needs to get the current state from the server without going through the
>      deltas. This is a copy from master to detail, deltas and performance
>      be damned.
> 3. **Client is suspicious**. In this case, you need to compare client against server to determine if the client is up-to-date and needs any
>      deltas.
>
> You should follow the database (and SVN) design pattern of
>   sequentially numbering every change. That way a client can make a
>   trivial request ("What revision should I have?") before attempting to
>   synchronize. And even then, the query ("All deltas since 2149") is
>   delightfully simple for the client and server to process.

Original Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413086/client-server-synchronization-pattern-algorithm/413136#413136

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, it's a difficult problem.  Source Control doesn't solve it very well - they still require manual intervention when it doesn't know what to do.  Often using a library that implements it for you is the way to go.  Figure out what you need to provide in order for third party libraries to identify conflicts, and then determine how they may be resolved.  Some software reject conflicts outright - look at bugzilla. If an issue is edited between you receiving the bug in your browser and submitting a comment, it will flat out reject your update.

Whether or not the client or the server determines a conflict does not matter.  It will occur at some point, and you need to 1) detect it, and 2) know what you're going to do in all cases of conflict.

I should add that I cooked my own sync scheme for data, and regretted not using third party libraries.